# Have two columns with full height background?

Tags: html, css, height

I would like to make a page with two columns of fixed width, each with their own background color, strechting over the entire height of the page, even when scrolling down for large content. A simple drawing for clarification: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3060536/twocol.png

I have found several solutions that *almost* do what I want.

- Putting `height:100%` everywhere, looks great as long as you don't scroll: this seems to be relative to the height of the screen (the background disappears when scrolling down for longer texts).
- Putting `height:100%` on html and body, and `min-height:100%` on one of the divs, I can make one column fill the entire height. But this needs to be done directly below body, and hence it seems not combinable with the centered two-columns lay-out that I want.
- Putting `padding-bottom:100000px` and `margin-bottom:-100000px` in the columns and `overflow-y:hidden` in the parent, works fine if everything fits on the screen, but it entirely removes the option to scroll down if the text doesn't fit on the screen.

So none of the above does what I want. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: you might be able to use something like this http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns (instead of giving your elements a background image/color)

Comment: Flexbox will work for you on modern browsers

Comment: @NickSlash That would work, but I still hope to find a solution without needlessly using image files for flat colors.

Comment: @CoryDanielson If only IE were dead... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get some idea here.. if position:relative does not bother you, try this.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>sample</title>
</head>

<body style="height:100%;">

<center>
    <div style="position:relative; width:900px; height:100%;">

        <div style="position:relative; float:left; background-color:blue; width:200px; height:auto; min-height:100%;">
            '//some texts or controls
        </div>


        <div style="position:relative; float:left; background-color:green; width:700px; height:auto; min-height:100%;">
            '//some texts or controls
        </div>

    </div>
</center>   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem work at all, it gives unequal height columns here. Could you re-check what you've written? I don't see why it should work, and indeed when testing it turns out it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

I've not tested this, and im pretty sure the `left: 50%; margin-left: -450px` doesn't work very well to center the elements. but its been a while since ive done html.

```
#background: {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 900px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -450px;
    background-color: red;
}
#background div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="background"><div></div></div>
```

**Update**

As I said, it was untested. It turns out I forgot to include the `height` or `bottom` for `#background`, possibly something else too.

Here's an example of the idea that does work http://jsfiddle.net/bEuTU/

Comment: Absolute positioning should be done only when absolutely necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with `absolute` positioning but this was just an example of having a layer behind the content that doesn't interact with it. I'm pretty sure the rest of the CSS is not pretty too.

Comment: What this does is making a blue fixed 200px sidebar aligned left. The red part isn't even visible. I'm afraid this way doesn't really work.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [blog post](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks). It took me a while to understand how it works but it does and it's great.

Comment: Could you please describe the solution or provide an example in your answer instead of linking to the blog post? I think this would be more helpful and be more specific to OP's question. There's also no guarantee the blog post will exist the next time someone wants to check this answer to the question.